# Is there a better alternative for "marriage seeker"?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms, phrasing

I'm trying to find an alternative for "marriage seeker"; ie, someone who asks for the other's hand in marriage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Question:** Is there a better alternative for “marriage seeker”?

**Answer:** Yes: there is [Courter](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/courter), [suitor](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/suitor), [inamorato](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/inamorato) and [fiancé](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/fianc%C3%A9).

#### Definitions

*Webster's Revised Unabridged Dictionary*, (1913), s.v [**Courter**](http://www.finedictionary.com/Courter.html):

> 1. One who courts; one who plays the lover, or who solicits in marriage; one who flatters and cajoles.

*Wordnet 3.6*, s.v. [**Suitor**](http://www.finedictionary.com/suitor.html)

> 1. A man who courts a woman; "a suer for the hand of the princess".

Wordnet 3.6 s.v. [**Inamorato**](http://www.finedictionary.com/inamorato.html): "1. A male lover."

*Webster's Revised Unabridged Dictionary*, 1913, s.v. inamorato

> **1.** A man with whom you are in love or have an intimate relationship.

*Webster's Revised Unabridged Dictionary*, 1913 s.v. **[Fiance](http://www.finedictionary.com/fiance.html)**: " 1. A betrothed man."

Wordnet 3.6 s.v. Fiance: "A man who is engaged to be married."

**Use in a sentence:** He was her courter, suitor, inamorato, or fiancé; she was indecisive on the matter, the exactness of their relationship.

Comment: I choose suitor.

Comment: As @MετάEd has said, 'Answers which consist of virtually nothing but an unsupported statement or a citation are not useful and may be subject to deletion – even correct answers. For help writing a good answer, see _How to Answer_.'

Comment: @EdwinAshworth As always, you should feel free to edit an answer you think is inadequate.

Comment: @sgroves I think I do more than my fair share of trying to stop the decline into mediocrity that various mods have warned about. Don't you feel that you could come up with something more helpful than your comment? // Here, I think it inappropriate to seek to improve an answer to a question I've close-voted.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I don't get the point of trying to get people to change their behavior when a) you're not a mod and b) you can edit posts.

Comment: Eh, pedants will be pedants. Upvoted this answer.

Comment: None of these is necessarily the *proposer.*

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to visit. I have updated the answer, hopefully it is an improvement. When it's such a simple question it may face deletion (yet the two word term returns no hits for the answer) one is tempted to present a simple answer; and comments are not for answers. - Note: On some other SE's if the answer is trivial it is autoconverted to a comment.

Comment: @Tonepoet - Thanks for the edit. At photo.SE a half dozen word answer is automatically converted to a comment, yet the same rule "no answers in comments, defeats voting" still applies. "Overwhelm" is OK, it ***is*** correct - each SE has it's own way. It was a matter of investment in a question that was simple enough. --- Referencing: https://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing and Answering: https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer (including a caution about well asked questions). I'll have to choose my questions carefully as I view points as valued at less than 1¢ each.